# Unable to update data using prepared statements in mysqli object oriented

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying this code to update tokens in my database but getting this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: stmt_i in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin-dashboard\action.php on line 185

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin-dashboard\action.php on line 185

```
 if(count($assoc_array)>0){
                        $token = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890jksdhfljdhfajlsdbhkfdajsfhaljsdfhb";
                        $token=str_shuffle($token);
                        $token=substr($token, 0,10);

    //                  echo $token;

                        $stmt_i->$conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET token=?, tokenExpire=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) WHERE email=?");
                        $stmt_i->bind_param("ss",$token,$femail);
                        $stmt_i-> execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

- set `$femail` variable
- prepare your statement with `prepare()` and assign the result to `$stmt_i` variable. Then bind each parameter value and execute your statement. Note, that [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) is a method of `mysqli` class, while [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) are methods of `mysqli_stmt` class.

  ```
  if (count($assoc_array) > 0) {
      $token = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890jksdhfljdhfajlsdbhkfdajsfhaljsdfhb";
      $token = str_shuffle($token);
      $token = substr($token, 0,10);
      $femail = 'some@email.com';

      $stmt_i = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET token=?, tokenExpire=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) WHERE email=?");
      $stmt_i->bind_param("ss", $token, $femail);
      $stmt_i->execute();
  }

  ?>
  ```

Comment: I  have already given the value to email above this if condition as:-  $femail=$_POST['femail'];
//  echo $femail;  and it is working data is receiving from the form.

Comment: @ChandraPrakash OK. Then assign the result from `$conn->prepare()` to `$stmt_i`.

Comment: Thank you very much the error has removed but still the value of token is not going to the database.

Comment: @ChandraPrakash Do you have a record with this e-mail? What does `echo $stmt_i->affected_rows;` return after `$stmt_i->execute();`?

Comment: Yes, I've e-mail record 0 (zero) is the answer in $stmt_i->affected_rows.

Comment: @ChandraPrakash If `$stmt_i->affected_rows` returns 0, than no records are updated. Check again the `$femail` value.

Comment: Thank you finally I resolved it . Should I keep this question or delete it?

Comment: @ChandraPrakash You may post your answer here, or accept one of the other answers. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question about deleting questions. Thanks.